# Why is it recommended that shell scripts end in a new line?

Tags: newline

Why is it recommended that shell scripts end in a new line? I noticed that many programmers leave an empty line at the end of their scripts. Is there a specific reason or POSIX recommendation?

Comment: I've read before that it makes them slightly easier to parse, same reason gcc wants/used to want a newline at the end of the file.

Comment: That makes sense. make that comment an answer and I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: super asked question previously. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287967/why-is-it-recommended-to-have-empty-line-in-the-end-of-file

Comment: I did not find that page awhile ago. I marked my question as a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, good question though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In many cases a line is defined as ending with a Newline, so you could say that by leaving it out your last "line" is not a line.

Works as expected

```sh
$ printf 'foo\n' > bar.txt

$ while read; do echo $REPLY; done < bar.txt
foo
```

No output here

```sh
$ printf 'foo' > qux.txt

$ while read; do echo $REPLY; done < qux.txt
```