# pyflakes enforce 1 single empty line at end of file?

Tags: vim, pyflakes, flake8

I am using flake8 with vim right now. I would like flake8 to show a lint warning if my file does not end with ONE single empty line at the end of file. I am very much used to the linter used at my old company

Is that enforceable?

Comment: Given that `pep8` actually *flags* blank lines at the end of a file,  I'm curious as to the rationale for requiring the opposite.

Comment: Are we talking actual empty line or EOL char at the znd of last line?

Comment: I am actually talking about 1 empty line at the end of each file. I forgot what the rationale is, but my old workplace was pretty adamant about this rule.

Comment: There are some answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287967/why-is-it-recommended-to-have-empty-line-in-the-end-of-file) as to why the empty line at EOF was necessary. But it seems to be an anachronism.