# Replacing lines in a file does not remove empty lines

Tags: php

I've this function to remove lines from a txt file:

```
function replace_file($path, $string, $replace)
    {
        set_time_limit(0);

        if (is_file($path) === true)
        {
            $file = fopen($path, 'r');
            $temp = tempnam('./', 'tmp');

            if (is_resource($file) === true)
            {
                while (feof($file) === false)
                {
                    file_put_contents($temp, str_replace($string, $replace, fgets($file)), FILE_APPEND);
                }

                fclose($file);
            }

            unlink($path);
        }

        return rename($temp, $path);
    }
```

Usage: `replace_file("file.txt", "line to remove", '');`

It is working perfectly but it always keep an empty line at the end of the file.

Is it possible to solve that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It is typically considered correct to leave an empty line at the end of a file. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2287990/2562137

Comment: If your only handling small files, then using [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and array walk then implode into a file would work just the same, but a more optimal solution for both big and small files would be to [use a generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43053295/661872), you can't fix the issue with your current code as your using FILE_APPEND, and won't know if its the last line to trim the new line.

Comment: @Sarcoma Why is that? (Technically speaking). I always remove it when I come across it; wondering if I should stop, lol.

Comment: @J.ScottElblein It's a hang over from older systems that expect an empty line before EOF. In PHP it's part of PSR-2.

Comment: [`set_time_limit(0)`](https://php.net/set_time_limit) Setting that to zero is a REALLY bad idea within a function call. Functions shouldn't have side effects like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only looking to remove the empty line at the end, have a look at [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php).

Answer (score 1):

I've edited the function to be like that:

```
function replace_file($path, $string, $replace)
    {
        set_time_limit(0);

        if (is_file($path) === true)
        {
            $file = fopen($path, 'r');
            $temp = tempnam('./', 'tmp');

            if (is_resource($file) === true)
            {
                while (feof($file) === false)
                {
                    file_put_contents($temp, str_replace($string, $replace, fgets($file)), FILE_APPEND);
                    file_put_contents($temp,
                        implode('', file($path, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)));
                }

                fclose($file);
            }

            unlink($path);
        }

        return rename($temp, $path);
    }
```

And now it works.