# What does a C++ preprocessor do when there's just a single `#` in a line - and nothing else?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c-preprocessor

Is this a valid line of C++? What is it supposed to mean?

```
#
```

What about this one:

```
# // a comment
```

Recent compilers seem to ignore it without errors nor warnings.

Does it "do nothing"? I have a header file where a "compatibility" section bombs out when compiled with g++ 7.4.0 in presence of such lines. It doesn't seem to trip up compilers that see this line excluded in an inactive `#if` branch.

**Note: gcc 7.4.0 on Debian Bionic (as of this writing) on Travis CI is tripped by such lines.**

Comment: As to why a compiler may "trip". Some text editors write text files without an end-of-line marker before the end-of-file marker. That can cause some older C or C++ preprocessors to not read the last line of the file. I recall a preprocessor adamantly failing to recognise an `#endif` (closing an include guard) that was visibly present when editing the file. The fix was an extra blank line (or line with a comment saying "don't remove this line") after that `#endif`.  For info, see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287967/why-is-it-recommended-to-have-empty-line-in-the-end-of-a-source-file

Comment: @Peter Good tip! In my case, the `#` was well before the last line.

Comment: While the behaviour I described seems different, it is an example of the way content of a source/header file may appear correct, but trip up a preprocessor.  Until it was isolated, the example I described caused headaches when the project source was copied between unix and windows machines (and run through `unix2dos()` or `dos2unix()`, depending on direction of copying), and then built. I can't help wondering if you've encountered another problem of that ilk - finding a "lower level" way of examining the file than a text editor may give some clues.

Comment: Oh not it’s just old gcc bugs, that’s all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both examples are valid, and they do nothing.

For the second example, first the comments are removed in [translation phase 3](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.phases#1.3):

> ... Each comment is replaced by one space character. New-line characters are retained. ...

which results in the first case, which is a preprocessor directive that is expanded in [translation phase 4](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.phases#1.4):

> Preprocessing directives are executed, ...

This preprocessor directive is valid, and is called a `Null directive`, and has no effect, as stated [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.null):

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> # new-line
>
> has no effect.

where [new-line](https://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.pre#nt:new-line) is literally the new-line character.

So the code you have shown is valid, and should be accepted by a conforming implementation.